# How do I create a scatter plot of frequencies of Boolean values by subject?

Tags: statistics, scatter-plot, spss

I have an SPSS dataset of ~900 cases with multiple cases per subject. I want to calculate the frequency of a number of Boolean parameters per subject and generate a scatter plot of these values against another variable. I have tried to generate a new variable for this but cannot find an appropriate method in the help or here.

Comment: To make the plot you want you will have to make a new dataset of the aggregated values. See the `AGGREGATE` command (you would simply sum the boolean values).